# Работа с файлом xls

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Работаю в pycharm и нужно выгрузить данные файла csv из excel. В самом файле информация разбита по столбцам, но pycharm ее показывает, как будто все в одном столбце. Как поступить?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')

print(dataset)
```

Comment: Вы не могли бы добавить пример исходного файла, то, что у вас получается в итоге и то, что вы на самом деле хотите видеть в качестве результата работы программы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция [pd.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) по умолчанию использует запятую в качестве разделителя полей. Если вы в результате получаете один столбец, то в вашем CSV скорее всего используется другой разделитель. Укажите его явно:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv', sep=';')
```